# What does Star Trek have against marriage and families?

Tags: star-trek

Slightly tongue-in-cheek, but thinking about it I can't think of a single* main character in any of the Star Trek shows who is married with kids. And yet in the traditional Navy (and other armed forces) it's common-place. In TNG we even know Enterprise is bigger to hold families but they are 'civilians'.

*OK as I write this I think of some exceptions, but none are a full family unit:

- Beverly Crusher obviously has a son... but is she married?
- Neelix has a normal family setup, for his species, but it is shown as a novelty due to so many differences to our norms
- Sisko has a son but again isn't he separated?

The main characters are typically not in their early twenties but mature, established officers. People who often would have families even though they might not feature in the show.

Are there any happily married Star Trek characters? It seems the only time characters have families or spouses, these are in some way dysfunctional or sources of strife, for the purposes of narrative.

Comment: Good question, but one that's already been asked here before :-)

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: No need to be sorry! It's still worthy of an upvote - there's nothing wrong with being a duplicate question.

Comment: You forget Mr. and Mrs. O'Brien.  They got married and had one child on TNG, and a second on DS9.  In DS9 their marriage was more rocky, but it was O'Brien and not marriage, that they had a thing against (sort of).  I've even seen quotes, probably on memory alpha, where they consciously picked on O'Brien as the relatable everyman that everyone felt bad for when something bad happened to him.  He got all the worst situations, and the rocky marriage as a result.

Comment: Crusher's and Sisko's spouses both died; they are not alone by choice. IIRC Sisko's wife actually died at the Battle of Wolf 359 when Picard was Locutus, and I think Wesley's father died in some sort of accident.

Comment: @Torisuda fuel to my argument. It's fairly uncommon for people of that age to have dead spouses. Even in the army... apparently the civilised 24th(?) century is pretty dangerous!